# Change UITableViewCell's imageview without default blue or gray selection style

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a Customized UITableViewCell and ImageView (& oder customized elements) added over it, 
on selection i change the image on ImageView but the default selection style color is also seen on my imageView. If i try to set selection style none on UITableViewCell,then the ImageView doesnt change its default image.
if set to gray result is same the cell takes blue color and shows in imageview.
if their a way out to change the image with allowing user selection on cell?

Comment: Can u post the code, how do u set the image view? and how do u change it on selection?

Answer (score 0):

set cell selection style to none and change imageview's image on the onTouch event...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == yourImageView)
    {
            //add your code for image touch here 
    }

}
```

hope it helps...